# Add zipcode and billing address to stripe payment form

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to setup stripe payment on my website
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-stripe-payment-gateway-in-php-1_1027.html

i tested it with demo and live and it work perfect,
But i am trying to add zip code in the form
I want to send the user billing address and zip code to stripe to verify it

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_7JKeM9chawSzwFaDDJAxpa3K"
    data-image="http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/themes/PHPGang_v2/img/logo.png"
    data-name="PHPGang.com"
    data-description="Download Script ($15.00)"
    data-amount="1500">
  </script>

</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stripe's [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) form has a number of [configuration options](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options). To collect ZIP/postal codes, simply add `data-zip-code="true"` to the list of attributes. Here's a [basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/1fvrtrdh/).

Note that the field for the ZIP/postal code will only appear if it is needed, as not all countries use it. Checkout uses the first 6 digits of the card number (the ["BIN"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29)) to determine the card's country and show or hide the ZIP code field. In the example above, start typing `424242` for the card number and the field will appear.